# Altering HTML through delimited PHP

Tags: php, html, loops, file-io

I have a simple HTML page as a wrapper, then a PHP function to read information from a file and separate it into div tags (think separating comments or forum posts). It reads from a .txt flat file that is delimited between each section. This delimiter is supposed to increment a variable, then create a new div tag based on the value i (). It works for number 1 (the initialiser) and then it increments once, but it fails to increment more than once.

So my question is essentially what am I doing wrong? Am I modifying my variables incorrectly, or am I outputting HTML wrong?

You can assume the file is being opened and closed properly.

```
while (!feof($file)){ 
    $currentPost = 1;   # this is the counter (i)
    $charA = fgetc($file);  # check for delimiterA
    $charB = fgetc($file);  # check for delimiterB
    $line = fgets($file);   # read THE REST OF THE LINE

    if ($charA == "$" && $charB == "!") { # this delimiter separates posts. 

        $currentPost = $currentPost + 1;
        echo "</div> <div class=\"col$currentPost\">";  # close last div, make new div

    } else if ($charA == "%" && $charB == "&") { # content is finished, close div
        echo "</div>";
    } else {
        echo "$charA$charB$line<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Initialize `$currentPost = 1;` before the loop, not inside it.

The way your doing it now resets the `$currentPost` to `1` every time the loop runs.

Answer (score 0):

each time the while get executed the   `$currentPost = 1;` is reexecuted this is what you are doing wrong , you need to get the first initialization out of the while